# Is it possible for me to prevent a user from modifying the inner text of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Suppose I'm developing a game on a website and the game's score is being held as the inner text of an element:

```
<div id="score">50</div>
```

When the game is over, the user has the option of submitting their score to the high scores list, corresponding to a table in my database. The score is extracted from the above `div` and then passed to the server through AJAX.

But between the time the webpage is loaded and the game is over, I want the game to not use any of the server side. Is this possible while preventing the user from cheating by opening the JS console and typing something like

```
$('#score').text('9912391912381191238120');
```

????

Comment: Not unless you send the score changes to the server upon each change, otherwise the user will be able to change it whatever you do.

Comment: @TinyGiant the score changes very often and I don't want all those AJAX calls! Also it would be nice if they could play it even when their internet is slow.

Comment: Even if you were to prevent them from changing the div value, they could still submit anything they want. You make an ajax call once the game is done to submit the score? There is nothing stopping someone from submitting their own ajax call containing their own value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general, rule of the thumb in developping lightclients is: The *security must never be based upon the client side*, for the reason that the client is being executed on a machine that is beyond your security environment.

Yes, an advanced user could hack your HTML page to introspect the interchange of data between client and server, and so, would be able to perform a call to the server with arbitrary data. Even could hack the HTML contents with a developping tool like Chrome's or Firefox's JS console, as you already have realised.

My advice is: Design your program so that the state of the game lies always *on the server side*.